# How do I make the yaml indent not indent lists?

Tags: indentation, filetype-yaml

OK so I would like to change the way that my yaml gets indented.

Right now my vim indents a yaml list like this:

```
list:
  - this
  - is
  - a list
dict:
  this: is a dict
```

I would like it to indent like this:

```
test:
- this
- is
- a list
dict:
  this: is a dict
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution that's more internal to vim, is to override `indentexpr` with a custom indent expression (most likely just overriding the builtin `indentexpr` for your specific instance).

The steps:

- define a filetype override, either in an `autocmd` (group) or in a `ftplugin` override (preferred).
- define a new (global, i.e. starting with a capital letter) function, say `MyYamlIndent(lnum)`
- Add logic that detects the dash led entries. The main workhorse is likely `getline(v:lnum)` and`getline(v:lnum-1)`. The goal:
- find the indent count (in spaces) for the previous line.
- check if the current line contains a dash, if not, return the default (`GetYAMLIndent(v:lnum)`)
- If there is a leading dash, return the previous line's leading indent (in count of spaces)

Answer (score 1):

### Python module [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) as [`equalprg`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27equalprg%27)

Installation of `ruamel.yaml` is possible with [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/quickstart/)

```
$ pip install ruamel.yaml
```

`ruamel.yaml` is python3 compatible, i.e. `pip3 install ruamel.yaml` works as well.
If you want to install it only in your home directory, use `pip install --user ruamel.yaml`.

Ensure that `import ruamel.yaml` works for the python version vim sees.

Configure `equalprg` of vim for yaml files with

```
augroup myequalprograms
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType yaml setlocal equalprg=python\ -c\ \'import\ sys;\ from\ ruamel.yaml\ import\ YAML;yaml=YAML();yaml.dump(yaml.load(sys.stdin),sys.stdout)\'
augroup END
```

Alternatively, place following line in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/yaml.vim`

```
setlocal equalprg=python\ -c\ \'import\ sys;\ from\ ruamel.yaml\ import\ YAML;yaml=YAML();yaml.dump(yaml.load(sys.stdin),sys.stdout)\'
```

Now you should be able to press `=ip` for your example to get the desired output.
I have tried it on my machine with python3 and it works.

---

- Note you could also use [`pyyaml`](https://pyyaml.org/) with

  ```
  setlocal equalprg=python\ -c\ \'import\ yaml,sys;print(yaml.dump(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin),default_flow_style=False))\'
  ```

  However, `pyyaml` changes order, removes comments and other things. `ruamel.yaml` explicitly tries to support the roundtrip of parsing and emitting without modifying these things.
- There is also the project [`pretty-yaml`](https://github.com/mk-fg/pretty-yaml) with a convenient command line interface

  ```
  $ python -m pyaml demo.yaml
  ```

  Note the unfortunate similarity of the name `pyaml` to `pyyaml`. The author has made the decision that lists should be indented and therefore does not help you:

  > - List items get indented, as they should be.
- Finally, you could contact the maintainer of [`$VIMRUNTIME/indent/yaml.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/indent/yaml.vim) to ask him whether he would consider to add an option to achieve your style:

  ```
  " Vim indent file
  " Language:         YAML
  " Maintainer:       Nikolai Pavlov <zyx.vim@gmail.com>
  " Last Change:      2017 Jun 13
  ```